# How to search by name in a file?

Tags: java

How to find by name in a file which has objects consists of names and age ?

I want to search it by name from the file.
I finished up to writing the objects into files and reading from the file.

```
Demo object1 = new Demo(100,"saran");
Demo object2 = new Demo(20 ,"nivas");

ArrayList<Demo> list=new ArrayList<>();
try {
    FileOutputStream file=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\SARANNIVAS\\Documents\\file\\obj");
    ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(file);
    list.add(object1);
    list.add(object2);
    out.writeObject(list);

    out.close();
    file.close();

    System.out.println("object has been serialized");

} catch(IOException ex)
{
     ex.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("exception is caught");
}


try {
    FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\SARANNIVAS\\Documents\\file\\obj");
    ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(file);
    ArrayList<Demo> list1=new ArrayList<>();
    list1=(ArrayList<Demo>)in.readObject();

    for(Demo d:list1) {
        System.out.println(d.a);
        System.out.println(d.b);
    }

} catch(IOException ex) { 
    System.out.println("IOException is caught"); 
}
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly? if(d.name.equals("wantedname")){System.out.println("youpi");return//or break;} not working?

Comment: no,its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your trying to search the array list that you read back from the file.  Is this correct?  You could search the list with something like...

```
public class DemoDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo object1 = new Demo(100,"saran");
        Demo object2 = new Demo(20 ,"nivas");

        List<Demo> list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(object1);
        list.add(object2);

        list
          .stream()
             .filter(d1 -> d1.name.equalsIgnoreCase("saran"))
                .forEach(d2 -> System.out.println(d2.name + " of age " + d2.age));
    }
}

class Demo {
    public final int age;
    public final String name;

    public Demo (int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: are we converting the list into streams and checking with the filter and producing the result.??